# Do I understand this MVC right?

Tags: symfony, reactjs, redux

I'm refactoring a large web app with another developer's help.  In my mind, the backend is organized like so:

```
Symfony PHP:   controller
PostgreSQL DB: model
```

As I understand it, the client-side browser is the 'view' of the server.

The frontend is additionally organized like this:

```
Redux.js:  model + controller          // this is all mildly simplified
React.js:  view
```

Is it, therefore, conceptually correct to consider the client-side browser as the view of the server's state, and further, that the browser maintains its own state, controller, and view of the server-side data?

I'm a server-side "expert" (emphasize the quotes), while my helper is a front-end pro.  We're deliberately trying to separate frontend and backend and restrict interaction to JSON payloads beyond the initial page load.  If I'm looking at the global organization of the project right, it'll really help me organize our master codebase.

Comment: That setup is actually pretty good and I don't understand what you are refactoring. I would love it to use your tech stack at my work.

Comment: We're refactoring *to* that organization *from* something much more sophomoric :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's particularly helpful to think of the client-side app as just a view of the server-side state anymore.

The client-side is its own MVC application. Strictly, I don't think react-redux is actually MVC. It's considered an alternative to MVC. React is the View in MVC, but also a little bit of the Controller, and redux is an opinionated way of using the Model. You should read more here: http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Motivation.html

#### Relationship of the client-side M to the server-side M

Maybe another way of thinking about this is that the server has a 'model' and a part of the redux state-tree is actually kind of a view of that 'model' (like a list of todos derived from and kept in sync with a todo table on the server-side).

Parts of the redux state-tree could also have nothing to do with the server-side 'models' and could just be useful for storing client-side state (like the current url/route).

My firm belief is to not worry too much about the terminologies too much and stick to first principles. The server has state, the client-app has state. A part of the client-app's state is derived from and/or synced to the server-side state. The rest of the client-app's state helps generate the UI that the user sees. As the user interacts with the app, code is triggered that manipulates the state. Once you write a simple react-redux app, you'll see where all these pieces go!

Comment: So you believe that a react-redux frontend is less of a view of server state, but more of a reflection/copy of server state?  Actions on the frontend's "copy" of the server state may or may not make changes to the original server state (after all, I think one of Redux's prized features is being able to rollback a state without server involvement)

Comment: But I completely sympathize with the viewpoint that both frontend and backend can be considered their own independent apps with independent state.  It's not one big MVC, but two MVC models interacting.

Comment: Yep. client-side state is a reflection/transformation of the server-side state. It need not be an exact copy. Also, its models are kept in sync with the server's models typically. 2 MVC models interacting is a good way to look at it, although in these cases usually the server-side app is only exposing APIs. So the V on the server-app is serving an API instead of an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right.

### The state of the application

React components maintain internal state. The state is updated via `this.setState` upon an event (e.g. click, mouse move, keyboard input, timeout, AJAX response, etc.). When `this.setState` is called, en entire re-render of the component is scheduled, after which, the component is then redrawn.

The cycle pretty much continues. You can think of React's state to work just like a traditional LAMP web app, that is, in an example web app, user submits a form, the page is updated with new content. Only that instead of you setting up the listeners, and [imperatively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) telling react what data to pass in to `this.setState`, with a traditional LAMP app, you do so [declaratively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) in the HTML declaration of the `<form>`, in the inputs that you define.

**Albeit, the above React vs LAMP example is probably a bad analogy, because React does not directly work with the server. It's your responsibility on how to design your code to work with the server.**

### Communication with server

So, with LAMP, trivially, if you want user input to persist on the server, you simply record the input from a form POST request.

With react, there's an extra step on your end.

When a user triggers an event (click, mouse move, keyboard input, etc.), you first need to issue an AJAX request, which, of course, the server will act on the request (e.g. store form input).

In the (successful) response callback, you would then call `this.setState` to update what the server responded with. With a traditional LAMP app, you would get an entirely new web page rendered with the user's persisted data. With React, instead, you get back some piece of data (perhaps JSON or XML) which isn't the web page, but is used by your front-end application to determine what the page should look like.

Comment: for the record, your answer was awesome too.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it, therefore, conceptually correct to consider the client-side
>   browser as the view of the server's state, and further, that the
>   browser maintains its own state, controller, and view of the
>   server-side data?

Yes, it is completely correct.

In fact, you can think about your web app as an MVC that lives inside another MVC (the browser) that is then executed inside another MVC (the OS windowing system). Which communicates with another MVC across the wire (your backend app).

Now, swap MVC for "the implementation of a software design pattern", because there is no canonical definition of what MVC is. There are many variations, for example, MVC in the server is quite different from MVC in a client machine.

> The server side approach is based on what is known as Java Model 2. This design shares the same philosophy as MVC and most of its components resemble it, so we all call it MVC. Which is not incorrect, although inexact too.
>
> http://givan.se/mvc-past-present-and-future/#server-mvc

You can compare all of the documented patterns that belong to the MVC collection here:
http://mvc.givan.se/